# google charts save graph, popup windows

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

I am making an application in visual studio with javascript and google charts.
I want to record the graphic, the options I found do not work in IE.

Take an example and modify it, I can move the image to another container `<img id = "chartImg" />`, on the same page and in this way to save png format.
I also think a popup window to charge image recording.
I can not create the image directly in the popup window, without passing the container `<img id = "chartImg" />` and then to the window. 
I do not want the container.

As I can create pop-up, directly from SVG is created by plotting with Google Chart API, pressing on a button or click me.

The code place it in jsFiddle.

[http://jsfiddle.net/rdmghzhm/3/](http://jsfiddle%20Google%20charts%20popup)

It is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
Right-click this image to save it:<br />
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>
<img id="chartImg" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function drawVisualizationDaily() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Daily', 'Sales'],
        ['Mon', 4],
        ['Tue', 6],
        ['Wed', 6],
        ['Thu', 5],
        ['Fri', 3],
        ['Sat', 7],
        ['Sun', 7]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var imgUri = chart.getImageURI();
        // do something with the image URI, like:
      document.getElementById('chartImg').src = imgUri;
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
        title:"Daily Sales",
        width:500,
        height:400,
        hAxis: {title: "Daily"}
    });
}  
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawVisualizationDaily});

function openWin() {  
   var divText = document.getElementById("chartImg").outerHTML;   
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=500');
   var doc = myWindow.document;
   doc.write('<img' + ' id="graficar" ' +' />');
   doc.write(divText);
   doc.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
   doc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide within a DIV, the image that you create on the main page, the code html would look like this.

```
<div id="visualization"></div>
Right-click this image to save it:<br />
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>
<div style="display:none;">
<img id="chartImg" />
</div>
```

In jsFiddle serious:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lx91o0e/

greetings

If there is a small mistake with Chrome, to create the pop-up window, it is still recording the image with right mouse button.
windows.open must call with complete parameter, this code works correctly in Chrome and elsewhere too, I could taste only in IE 11

```
 var myWindow = window.open("about:blank", "Save graph", "location=0,resizable,status=0,menubar=0,titlebar=0,left=5,top=5");
```

Comment: The new code works correctly in IE, Opera and Firefox, but Chrome can not record the image of the popup. I'll look for that.